# Проходимец ― почему у слова негативный оттенок?

Tags: этимология, словообразование, значение-слов

Проходимцем называют нечистого на руку человека, неизвестно кого ― одним словом, понятие несет негативный оттенок. При этом тот, кто прокладывает путь, ― первопроходец.

Какая разница между "проходцем" и "проходимцем"?
Почему разница эта заключается именно в характере слова?
Да и вообще, интересно, почему мошенника называют проходимцем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проходимец - достаточно новое в русском языке слово. Впервые в литературном тексте его употребил Пушкин, и сразу в негативном смысле :

> А. С. Пушкин. История Петра: Подготовительные тексты (1835-1836)
> Петр повелел заплатить сполна ему всё жалование, также сердится на присылку **какого-то венецианского проходимца** Контия; утешает Головкина о кончине его матери, умершей в преклонных летах, и проч. etc.
> (Нацкорпус)

В словарях той эпохи (18 - первая половина 19 вв) *проходимец* не отмечен. А были вот такие синонимы :
**про'ходень** (церк.), **прошле'цъ**, **проидо'ха**. Все они имеют практически один и тот же морфемный состав, с вариациями корня *ид/ход*. Появление еще одного слова с тем же составом и неодобрительным значением вполне закономерно. Ср. : прошлец - проходимец.

Дополнение.
Здесь можно также задуматься о возможной логике образования/понимания слова *проходимец*. Сравнив с *лихоимцем* и *мздоимцем*, можно так обозначить его возможный смысл : проходИМец - проход (всюду) ИМеющий - пролаз и проныра по Далю.

Comment: Да, история слова очень часто проясняет его значение. А из какого источника взяты эти сведения? И почему в приведенных здесь ответах были ссылки на Даля, который вроде бы считал проходимца просто странником?

Comment: Заглянем в Даля :  
> Проходень м. церк. скиталец, бродяга;
|| проходень, проходим, проходимец,
проходимка , прошлый человек, пришлец м.
пройдоха , пройда об. пролаз, проныра,
пройдошливый человек, хитрый плут, от
которого ничего не уйдет.
Прошлянка , проходимка ж. пройдошливая
женщина; но
|| проходимец и проходимка также странник,
путник, особенно идущий на поклонение,
паломник. Ковровцы - офени, коробейники,
проходимцы.

Comment: Как-то у Даля всё не очень отчетливо. Непонятно, какое значение является старшим, когда появилась негативная оценка, когда просто странников перестали называть проходимцами. Это, наверное, можно установить только по реальным текстам и историческим комментариям на эту тему.

Comment: Логика словообразования, действительно, интересная. Может быть, проходимец - это изначально странник, а проходим - это имеющий проход, как мздоимец - имеющий мзду. А потом мошенник-проходим вытеснил проходимца-странника и сам стал называться проходимцем.

Comment: По данной ссылке http://wordhist.narod.ru/pred.html (В.В.Виноградов) есть несколько мнений об этимологии *проходимца*.

Comment: Там вроде бы рассматривается только суффикс ИМ, но, мне кажется, возможно взаимное влияние слов и их сближение с другими словообразовательными схемами. Например, подхалим ведь не стал подхалимцем.

Comment: У  Даля  всё  не  очень   отчётливо,  потому,  что  его  словарь  фактически  диалектологический,  но  наличие  синонимического  ряда  -  пролаз,  пройдоха,  проходимец  -  вполне  отчётливо.

Answer (score 3):

У Ефремовой  в словаре слово проходимец значит "человек, проходящий через какую-либо местность". Если заглянуть в словарь Даля, то в нём тоже говорится, что"ПРОХОДИМЕЦ" - странник (путник), это человек с чужбины, проезжий, гость. ( от глагола проходить). В толковом словаре Ожегова дано современное вторичное (внесённое социальной составляющей) значение слова проходимец - "мошенник, негодяй", потому что странники зачастую оказывались безнравственными бродягами, норовившими что-то украсть, обмануть, появился негативный оттенок, второе значение, а первое утратилось, перешло на слово"странник". Странники раньше были идейными, религиозными, странствовали с какой-то целью, а потом все люмпены стали "странниками", бездомными (=БОМЖами), их стали опасаться, как любого мошенника.

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/231584/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%86

Comment: Это совершенно верно. Единственное, что можно добавить к вашему ответу, то, что мошенник-проходимец, как правило, не привязан к дому, не имеет семьи и странствует по миру, живя обманом и воровством. Это его образ жизни. В приступном мире существует понятие "бродяга" - это уважительный термин среди уголовников. Революция и гражданская война породила эту категорию людей, вспомните Остапа Бендера, бывшего бродягой и истинным проходимцем.

Comment: Значение слова "проходимец" считывается с его морфемного состава, суффикс страдательного причастия ИМ ясно говорит нам о том, что речь идет о способности пройти: раньше у нас были проходимые и непроходимые леса и болота, теперь мы рассуждаем о проходимости нашего транспорта. Поэтому проходимец - это человек, способный пройти в любое место, и вряд ли нравственные качества странников могли бы как-то на это значение повлиять. Поэтому проходимец в нашем языке  был обречен стать мошенником, даже если изначально был хорошим человеком.

Comment: Но тогда и любимец, исходя из морфемного состава, негативный смысл, как-то не сходится. Способность пройти - не негативный смысл, а очень даже положительный, если пройти честно, опять нравственный смысл - при чём тут состав?Проходимец-проходит мимо, нигде не задерживается, ни к чему не привязан, способен на всё- вот и нравственность.

Comment: Где-то правила создают слова, которыми пользуется народ, а где-то и народ диктует. В этом случае диктует народ. А для того, чтобы придти к истине, иногда неплохо оторваться от компьютера и справочников и просто пообщаться с людьми.

Comment: > (...) суффикс страдательного причастия ИМ ясно говорит нам о том, что речь идет о способности пройти: раньше у нас были проходимые и непроходимые леса и болота, теперь мы рассуждаем о проходимости нашего транспорта.

По поводу проходимости транспорта вспомнилось. Слышал пару раз, как автомобиль **внедорожник** называли словом **"проходимец"**. :-)

Comment: Любить - глагол переходный, речь идет об объекте действия. А идти - глагол непереходный, речь идет о субъекте действия. Мимо проходит "человек проходящий", а "проходимые люди" - это те, которые СПОСОБНЫ везде пройти. При этом  народом замечено, что честным людям такое плохо удается.

Comment: Народ - носитель языка, в данном случае он диктует следующее: проходимец (разг. презр.) - мошенник, негодяй, прохвост, что и зафиксировано как в речи, так и во  всех словарях, от которых надо оторваться. Так что, Сашка, не подскажете ли Вы какой-нибудь другой путь к истине (смайлик)?

Answer (score 2):

Проходимец

Образовано суффиксальным способом  "проходим – проходимец"  (от  "проходить") по тому же принципу, что и пройдоха. Также "проныра" - пронырливый, хитрый, ловкий в делах, обычно не очень честный человек.

Итак, проходим/проходимец - это тот, который  везде пройдет, пронырнет, проберется, для чего нужна ловкость, хитрость и часто применение нечестных способов.

Первопроходец

Первопроходец - это тот, кто прошел сложный путь первым, преодолев все трудности. Это, конечно, герой.